# Is there a method to run a script safely

Tags: perl

I'm trying to delete log files on a server. But before the script is actually deleting files, I wan't to see which files would be deleted. My question is, is there a way to show which files would be deleted without actually deleting them? Preferably over a parameter.

Like this:

```
perl -- DeleteLogs.pl C:\Logs 14 -safeRun
```

**C:\Logs** is the path where the logs are saved.
**14** is the amount of days. Every file older than this argument should be deleted.
**-safeRun** this should be the argument who tells the script just to print out which files will be deleted but don't delete it yet.

**The Script**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);
use File::Basename;
use local::lib;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
use File::Basename;
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
use DateTime::Duration;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use Time::Local;
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds 'ONE_WEEK';


my $logPath = $ARGV[0];
my $leaveLog = $ARGV[1];
my $file;
my $filename;

if (not defined $logPath) {
    die "Need a correct path\n";
}

if (-d $logPath) {

    print "Directory exist\n";

    if (looks_like_number($leaveLog)) {

        print "Everything correct";
        DoDir($logPath);

    }
    else {

        die "$leaveLog isn't a correct Integer"
    }

}
else {

    die "Directory don't exist\n"
}

sub DoDir {

    my $dir = shift;

    opendir(DIR, $dir) || die "Unable to open $dir: $!";
    my(@files) = grep {!/^\.\.?$/} readdir(DIR);
    closedir(DIR);

    foreach (@files) {

        if (-d ($file = "$dir\\$_")) {
            print "Found a directory: $file\n";
            DoDir($file);
        }
        else {

            checkDate($file);
        }
    }
}

sub checkDate {

    $filename = basename($file);

    #Regex for pattern "Normalfall"
    #Bsp: 2019_07_02_TEST_SERVER_ALL.log
    if ($filename =~ m/^\D?20\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{2}_[\w_]+.log$/) {

        #Regex: "\D?" match any char thats not a digit.
        #       "\d{2}\_" expecting 2 random digits and underscore
        #       "[\w_]+." expecting 1 to unlimited word char. matches with underscore char
        #       "log"  matches with the characters log (case sensitive)
        NormalFile();


    }
    #wl-deploy-181205082159_TEST-server_server-2019.log
    elsif($filename =~ m/^wl-deploy-\d+_[\w\-_.]+\d+\.log$/) {

        #Regex: "^" asserts position at start of a line
        #       "wl-deploy-" matches the character (case sensitive)
        #       "\d+" matches with a digit [0-9]
        #       "[\w\-_.]+"
        #           "\w" matches any word char [a-zA-Z0-9]
        #           "\-" matches the char -
        #           "_." matches a single char in the list _.
        DeployFile();
    }
    #2019_06_30_TestAdapter_BackendLog.log.gz_2019-07-03
    elsif ($filename =~ m/^\D?20(\d{2}_){3}[\w_]+\.log\.gz_\D?20(\d{2}-){2}\d{2}$/) {

        #print "$filename: File match .log.gz\n";
    }
    #stdout.log.190529100348-190605092829.gz_2019-06-07
    elsif ($filename =~ m/^stdout\.log(\.\w+?-\w+?(\.gz_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})?)?$/) {

        #Regex: "stdout" matches the chars
        #       "\." matches the char .
        #       "log" macthes the char log (case sensitive)
        #       "(\.\w+?-\w+?(\.gz_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})?)?"
        #           "?" matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible
        #           "\w+?" matches aby word chars
        #           "+?" matches between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible
        #           "(\.gz_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})?" 2nd Capturing Group
        #               "\d{4}" matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
        #               "\d{2}" matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
        #               "\d{2}" matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
        StdoutFile();
        #print "$filename: File match stdout\n";
    }
    #2019-01-13-18-45.wl-test.error
    elsif ($filename =~ m/^\D?20\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\.[\w\-]+\.error$/) {

        #Regex: "[\w\-]"
        #       "\w" matches any word character
        #       "\-" matches the character - literally
        ErrorFile();
    }
    #TT_TestAccessImpl_Statistic0.log.lck
    elsif ($filename =~ m/^[\w]{2}\_[\w]+\.log\.lck$/) {

        #Regex:
        LckFile();
    }
    #server.log00335
    elsif ($filename =~ m/^server\.log(\d{5})?$/) {

        #print "$filename: File Match server\n";
        ServerFile();
    }
    #access.log00021
    elsif ($filename =~ m/^access\.log(\d{5})?$/) {

        #print "$filename: File match access\n";
    }
    else{

        print "$filename: don't match\n";
    }
}


sub NormalFile() {

    my $chars = substr($filename, 0 , 10);

    my $date_parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(

        pattern  => '%Y_%m_%d',
        on_error => 'croak',
    );

    my $dt = $date_parser->parse_datetime($chars);
    my $day14 = DateTime->now->subtract (days => $leaveLog);
    my $cmp = DateTime->compare($day14, $dt);

    if ($cmp == -1 || $cmp == 0) {
        print "don't delete\n";
    }
    else {
        print "delete File: $file\n";
        unlink $file;
    }
}

sub DeployFile() {

    $filename =~ s/[^\d]//g;
    my $dateFromString = substr($filename, 0 , 6);

    my ($year, $month, $day) = unpack("(a2)*", $dateFromString);
    $year = "20".$year;

    my $dateFromFile = $year."_".$month."_".$day;

    my $date_parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(

        pattern  => '%Y_%m_%d',
        on_error => 'croak',
    );

    my $dt = $date_parser->parse_datetime($dateFromFile);

    my $day14 = DateTime->now->subtract (days => $leaveLog);
    #print "$day14\n";

    my $cmp = DateTime->compare($day14, $dt);
    #print "$cmp\n";

    if ($cmp == -1 || $cmp == 0) {
        print "don't delete\n";
    }
    else {
        print "delete File: $file\n";
        unlink $file;
    }
}

sub LckFile {

    print "$filename delete\n";
}

sub ErrorFile {

    $filename = substr($filename, 0 , 10);
    $filename =~ s/-/_/g;

    my $date_parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(

        pattern  => '%Y_%m_%d',
        on_error => 'croak',
    );

    my $dt = $date_parser->parse_datetime($filename);

    my $day14 = DateTime->now->subtract (days => $leaveLog);
    #print "$day14\n";

    my $cmp = DateTime->compare($day14, $dt);
    #print "$cmp\n";

    if ($cmp == -1 || $cmp == 0) {
        print "don't delete\n";
    }
    else {
        print "delete File: $file\n";
        unlink $file;
    }
}

sub StdoutFile {

    print "$filename\n";
    $filename =~ /^stdout\.log\.((?:\d+?)|unknown)-(\d+?)(?:\.gz_\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})?$/g;

    unless (defined $1 and defined $2) {
        warn "Log file '$filename' does not match regex\n";
        return;
    }

    if ($1 ne "unknown") {

        my $firstDate = substr($1, 0, 6);
        my ($year, $month, $day) = unpack("(a2)*", $firstDate);
        $year = "20" . $year;
        $firstDate = $year . "_" . $month . "_" . $day;
    }

    my $secondDate = substr($2, 0, 6);
    my ($year, $month, $day) = unpack("(a2)*", $secondDate);
    $year = "20" . $year;
    $secondDate = $year . "_" . $month . "_" . $day;

    my $date_parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(

        pattern  => '%Y_%m_%d',
        on_error => 'croak',
    );

    my $dt = $date_parser->parse_datetime($secondDate);

    my $day14 = DateTime->now->subtract ( days => $leaveLog);
    #print "$day14\n";

    my $cmp = DateTime->compare($day14, $dt);
    #print "$cmp\n";

    if ($cmp == -1 || $cmp == 0) {
        print "don't delete\n";
    }
    else {
        print "delete File $file\n";
        unlink $file;
    }
}

sub ServerFile {
    #print "$filename delete\n";
}
```

Comment: You have to modify the script, but we can't tell you how, as you haven't shown it. Or, make a copy of the files and run the script there.

Comment: @choroba addet the script

Comment: Set a flag (variable meant to be "true" or "false") based on that command line option (to delete or not), and then make the deletion of files  conditional on this variable. To nicely deal with command line options use [Getopt::Long](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html)

Comment: Perhaps https://perldoc.perl.org/Safe.html, https://perldoc.perl.org/ops.html

Comment: I typically set a `debug` flag. then if debug true, it will `print` the result instead, if set to false, then perform the actual delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would:

1) add a new global array `my @dfiles;`

2) change all your `unlink $file;` statements to `push @dfiles, $file;`

3) add code at the end of main that displays the files:

```
print "These are the files that would be deleted:\n";
for (@dfiles) {print; print "\n"}
```

I'll leave it up to you how you want to handle whether files actually get deleted, either by switch or by y/n prompt. But if the files are to be deleted, then just:

```
for (@dfiles) {unlink $_}
```